# Join two postgresql queries

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query

```
SELECT role_uuid FROM users WHERE email = 'email@domain.com'
```

I also have a `roles` table the following fields:

- `uuid`
- `name`
- `created_at`

I'm hoping to have 1 query that gives lets me select the role by `email` and get the `name` and `created_at` field from the roles table.

I've tried things like this but I can't quite figure it out.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = 'email@domain.com') AS A
JOIN ( SELECT * FROM roles WHERE uuid = A.role_uuid) AS B
WHERE A.role_uuid = B.uuid
```

Answer (score 2):

You JOIN the two tables which gives you a table with all the fields from both source tables. Then you use WHERE to filter and SELECT to specify the fields that you want to be returned.

```
SELECT r.name, r.created_at
FROM users u JOIN roles r ON (u.role_uuid = r.uuid)
WHERE u.email = 'email@domain.com'
```

If you run into naming conflicts because of fields from both tables sharing the same name you can use AS to define fieldnames for the output columns:

```
SELECT r.name AS rolename, u.name AS username, r.created_at
FROM users u JOIN roles r ON (u.role_uuid = r.uuid)
WHERE u.email = 'email@domain.com'
```

Comment: this works great as requested but what happens if the row from each table are the same?